# C++ Interaction between two classes in a function

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to do a relatively simple task here and am not sure how to go about it.

I have two classes of interest `Parent` and `Child`. Both of them are a special case of the class Human. I create them as such.

Relevant bit of **main.cpp**:

```
int main() {
    //create an object of class Parent parent1 with a name Albert.
    Parent parent1("Albert");

    //create an object of a class Child child1 named John.
    Child child1("John");
    return 0;
}
```

The **Parent.h** header includes a function called `addChild()`. What it does is simply adds a child to a vector of Children inside a Parent object.

Relevant bit of **Parent.h**:

```
class Parent: public Human {
public:
    vector<Human> Children;

   ...
void addChild(Human aHuman){
        Children.push_back(aHuman);
    }

  };
```

What I would like to achieve is for the `addChild()` function to simultaneously add a parent to the child as well. That is, to do something like:

```
void addChild(Human aHuman) {
        Children.push_back(aHuman);
        aHuman.Parent = MYSELF;
    }
```

Above, MYSELF denotes the bit that I do not know how to code up.

So when I run this:

```
int main() {
    //create an object of class Parent parent1 with a name Albert.
    Parent parent1("Albert"); 

    //create an object of a class Child child1 named John.
    Child child1("John");

    parent1.addChild(child1);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like Albert to be set as a parent of John and John as a child of Albert.

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:

The code as per Jan's suggestion:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

class Human{

};

class Child;

class Parent : public Human
{
    std::vector<Child> children;
public:
    friend Child;
    void addChild(Child& child)
    {
        children.emplace_back(child);
        child.parents.emplace_back(*this);
    };
};

class Child : public Human
{
    std::vector<Parent> parents;
public:
    friend Parent;
    void addParent(Parent& parent)
    {
        parents.emplace_back(parent);
        parent.children.emplace_back(*this);
    }
    ;
};
```

Errors:

```html
In member function 'void Parent::addChild(Child&)':
invalid use of incomplete type 'class Child'
         child.parents.emplace_back(*this);
error: forward declaration of 'class Child'
 class Child;
```

Comment: Is there a `Human` who is no child? What *does* (functionality) a `Parent` which a `Human` (or `Child`) doesn't? In short: your design is not very useful.

Comment: This is a toy example to illustrate what I want the function addChild() to do - I am not worried about the design at this point.

Comment: MYSELF is `this` resp. `*this`

Comment: Why not simply use `this` ?

Comment: In non-static members of any class, the `this` pointer (supplied by the compiler) identifies the current object.    Beyond that, children and parents are not distinct types of human  (quite a few people are both simultaneously).   I therefore would not use `Human` as a base class.   Instead, do without `Parent` and `Child` as distinct classes.    Then each `Human` can have a set of children, and a set of parents   i.e.   being a parent or a child (or having parents and children) is an attribute of each `Human`, not the basis for defining different types of `Human`.

Comment: See my answer update on your added question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered a common problem of novice OOP programmers: You try to solve a relational problem by extending OOP classes, instead of creating a relational class.

**The novice approach**

First, let's continue with your approach for a bit... Of course, each `Parent` has a `Child` and each `Child` has a `Parent`, and the natural way seems to store these relations inside each class. Thus:

```
class Parent : public Human
{
    std::vector<Child> children;
  public:
    void addChild(const Child& child);
};

class Child : public Human
{
    std::vector<Parent> parents;
  public:
    void addParent(const Parent& parent);
};
```

Now, let's implement the `add...` functions:

```
void Child::addParent(const Parent& parent)
{
    parents.emplace_back(parent);
}
void Parent::addChild(const Child& child)
{
    children.emplace_back(child);
}
```

As you already mentioned, this requires you to update the parent and the child separately. So, let's change our approach and make the classes friends:

```
class Child;
class Parent : public Human
{
    std::vector<Child> children;
  public:
    friend Child;
    void addChild(Child& child);
};

class Child : public Human
{
    std::vector<Parent> parents;
  public:
    friend Parent;
    void addParent(Parent& parent);
};
```

This friend relation can now be used to update the other class as well:

```
void Child::addParent(Parent& parent)
{
    parents.emplace_back(parent);
    parent.addChild(*this);
}
void Parent::addChild(Child& child)
{
    children.emplace_back(child);
    child.addParent(*this);
}
```

Damn, this does not work! What happened? We effectively created an infinite loop. Because adding a `Child` to a `Parent` adds the child, but also calls the `addParent` function on the child, which then adds the parent, but also has to call the `addChild` function on the parent, which adds a child, ... you get the point.

How can we fix that? One way is to add the child/parent another way:

```
void Child::addParent(Parent& parent)
{
    parents.emplace_back(parent);
    parent.children.emplace_back(*this);
}
void Parent::addChild(Child& child)
{
    children.emplace_back(child);
    child.parents.emplace_back(*this);
}
```

This works, but we have to pay a heavy cost for that. The `Parent` and the `Child` have to know the internals of each other to work properly. This means, you cannot easily change these classes, and it is hard for users to extend them. (They need to study your whole class internals to be sure that it works.)

Furthermore, there are several other problems with this approach:

- What happens if we change the line order in the `addParent` or `addChild` function? (Hint: We save a copy of the object without the proper elements added.)
- How can you remove a child from a parent and update the parents of the child properly?
- How can you be sure as a parent, that the child does not change your internal behaviour in a weird way, or vice-versa?

Moreover, we are using copies of the objects inside the classes right now. This means, that updating a parent will leave the actual data inside the child untouched (and vice-versa). This can partly be solved by using pointers, but also means that you have to begin managing pointers for this simple task...

**The method approach**

So, what is a proper solution? One easy option, is a functions which deals with these interconnected updates. Taking the first implementation (without updating both parent and child), we can use the following function:

```
void linkChildToParent(Parent& parent, Child& child)
{
    parent.addChild(child);
    child.addChild(parent);
}
```

The `linkChildToParent` function...

- will update your child and your parent correctly.
- does not depend on line ordering.
- is easy to read and maintain.
- is easy for users of `Child` and `Parent` to extend.

This approach solves most of our problems and can even be extended to deal with pointers properly and very easily. Yet, we still have to put some work into updating the right members, ... How is this fixed? By proper OOP of course!

**The OOP approach**

The problems we are having are all related to the way we store the relation between a parent and its child. This is an indicator, that our abstraction is wrong! Thinking about it, we can come up with the right abstraction, a `ParentalRelation` class:

```
//Given, that we only have basic functionality, a struct is sufficient here...
struct ParentalRelation
{
    Child child;
    Parent parent;
};
```

This allows us to store parent-child information in a separate table. Furthermore:

- `Child` and `Parent` do not need to know nothing about their internals.
- Extending any of the classes is easy.
- Deleting or changing parents/children is very easy.
- It is frankly much less code to understand and to write.

In addition, a switch to pointers is easily done because only `ParentalRelation` is needed to manage them. This has the advantage of always having the right information, when either the parent or child is changed, without additional update code.

**Disclaimer**

- I hope, this was somewhat clear.
- While it might seem easy here, finding the `ParentalRelation` approach can be very difficult in practice.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for such a detailed explanation - much appreciated for a newbie. I think I am still encountering a forward declaration issue - can you help? I have added the code and errors it yields in the edit of the question.

Comment: Your code will not compile nor work, since a container has to know the size of its elements. (In this case `std::vector<Child>`)

Comment: @Kivis No problem! Sorry, this is a bit tricky and I left out some implementation details to make the code clearer... Here, you cannot define the member functions inside the class. You have to declare them and then do the definition outside. Here is a working implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/Hd4xhP

Comment: @Superlokkus Despite your prediction, it compiles and it works :D As far as I understand it (this might be wrong), `std::vector<Child>` is just a pointer to a memory location, and because pointers have a type independent size, the compiler already has all the information it needs to compile `Parent`.

Comment: My misconception is that they changed the type requirement of T in vector<T>, from complete type from C++11 to C++14 to allocator completeness requirements in C++17.

Comment: But thanks in regard that If you had not told me, I would have not noticed that change in C++17.

Comment: @Superlokkus I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what you are saying.

Comment: Your code is still wrong for C+11 and 14 and will not guaranteed compile for pre C++17 standard libraries. Thats also the reason why it did not compile on the online compiler given by the OP.

Comment: @Superlokkus B b but it compiles... a a and works... (See https://godbolt.org/z/Hd4xhP ) You just have to get the order of declarations and definitions right....

Comment: @Superlokkus Comparing you code with mine: You define a single parent for the child. You are right, this does not work... However, that's not what I am doing. I have a vector, which just works fine.

Comment: @Superlokkus I think, I understand you problem now.  I posted it as a separate question at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56975491/4759339

Comment: Everything works for me. Thanks Jan! And I am glad this started a discussion :)

Comment: @jan.sende I was wondering, why do you also add the address operator & after Parent and Child in the addChild, addParent and  linkChildToParent functions? I am trying to understand this whole memory address and pointers business at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: @Kivis The `&` can have multiple meanings. At this point it marks the parameters as a [reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)). They behave somewhat like pointers, but are not exactly the same. You need them because `Parent parent` would edit a copy of the object and leave the original behind. However, one could write a `Parent* parent` version instead.

Answer (score 3):

I fear that you have a XY Problem and mixing up important concepts of object polymorphism and C++ design in general but, here is a solution to what you asked:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Human {
    virtual ~Human() = default;
};

struct Parent;

struct Child: Human{
    Child(std::string) {}
    void addParent(std::weak_ptr<Parent> aParent) {
        Parent = aParent;
    }
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Parent> Parent;
};

struct Parent: Human, std::enable_shared_from_this<Parent> {
    Parent(std::string) {}
    void addChild(Child aChild){
        aChild.addParent(shared_from_this());
        Children.push_back(aChild);

    }
private:
    std::vector<Child> Children;
};



int main() {
    auto parent1 = std::make_shared<Parent>("Albert"); //create an object of class Parent parent1 with a name Albert.
    Child child1("John");//create an object of a class Child child1 named John.
    parent1->addChild(child1);
}
```

It ain't pretty, but thats more to the problems of your design i.e. question.

Note that this code is still far from optimal with all this call by value, copying, lifetime and irrelevance of the `Human` class. However better solutions would need more context and design.

**Update on Update**
**Update on Jahns code**
Jahns code is not valid from C++11 to C++14:
As you asked whats wrong with jans code: It does not compile because it will not work in general. As `std::vector<T>` requires a complete type, and is basically equivalent as storing a copy of `T`.
Since C++17:
Jahns code should run, but because now `std::vector<T>` can also work as storing a reference to `T`, basically equivalent to the tricks described below.

Because of your design you have 2 classes with a circular dependency: Childs should save their parents and parents their childs. So you i.e. Jan decided to save a copy of parent in the child and a copy of the child in parent. But in order to save it, a computer has to know  how big it is.

So child has to know how big a parent is to know how big itself will be, but in order to know how big a parent is, it has to know first how big itself is, because its also saved in parent. See the problem? Self reference is a devils playground and usually leads to infinite recursion.

However a trick to break the cycle is, to just say to child, "don't save the whole parent, just a reference to it, so you don't need to know how big it is". This is done by the forward deceleration of parent, and the usage of *smart pointers*, which safe you from doing bad things, like trying to  use a blank reference. (Thats way raw pointers like `Parent*` are bad, don
t use them, you probably will get *undefined behavior*, i.e. seg faults on fridays 2 function calls late)

Another very similar common trick would be that child and parent agreed on the same root, like a human base class. It also solves the problem by using references. You human class suggests you first tried or your teacher urged you to go this way.

But all those tricks increase complexity and lower performance and safety, because you pushed work from compile time to runtime. Java, C#, Python and Co. are even doing this per default. Makes anti patterns more common IMHO.

I can only repeat: I recommend to read a book on C++, C++ Primer by Lippman is what I read as a beginner.

Comment: Isn't adding `weak_ptr` / `shared_ptr` to code of someone who is learning is way overcomplicated?

Comment: Yes, but since he/she seems stubborn with the given class design, it has to be done.  Otherwise you would get even more surprising effects like, slicing and lifetime issues i.e. seg faults. That way I already recommended the OP to reconsider his/her initial design. And further learn about lifetime, storage classes and OOP in general.

Sure one could just refuse to answer newbie questions because they are wrong, but given one does not, at least one should show good practice where possible. And raw pointers are unsafe and not best pratice.

Comment: Please have a look at my comment, and my [implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/Hd4xhP). It seems like you have a misconception on how `std::vector` works.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. That is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You have mainly 2 issues:

- You pass by value instead of reference, so you only modify a copy
- You have object slicing: `std::vector<Human>` only store Human part of `Parent`/`Child`.

Answer (score 0):

you have an issue when you using void addChild(Human aHuman) without & you need to do void addChild(Human& aHuman) if you what the changed to save in the object without & you copy 2 times the objects  1 in the call to function and one  when you insert to addChild(child1); 
MYSELF can be this but you need to change the vector not to get objects