# Why does std::vector work with incomplete types in class definitions?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std, stdvector

The following question came up:

The c++ standard seems to say, that `std::vector` requires a complete type to work. (See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector ) Then, why does the following code still compile?

```
#include <vector>

struct parent;

struct child
{
    std::vector<parent> parents; //parent is incomplete here!
};

struct parent
{
    std::vector<child> children;
};
```

This seems counterintuitive. If `std::vector` requires a complete type, then `std::vector<parent>` should not compile because only its forward declaration is known inside the class definition of `child`.

- Is this behaviour something special about class definitions?
- Did I get it wrong, and `std::vector` does not require a complete type?
- Or, is this just a fluke? In that technically this isn't allowed, but it works for all implementations anyways...

**EDIT**

There seems to be a difference between c++11 and c++17. I would like to understand the c++11 version.

Comment: I think the problem resides in the fact that parent isn't really an incomplete type because you explicitly defined it.

Comment: @AdrienGivry Yes it is incomplete while defining the `child` class

Comment: C++11 needs complete; C++17 however: _"This container (but not its members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element type if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector  Please add the standard version to the question/

Comment: `parent` needs to be complete to instantiate your `std::vector<parent>`, which is done when you instanciate a `child`. If you don't instanciate a `child`, your code will compile. If you instantiate a child somewhere, make sure that `parent` is completly defined at this point.

Comment: @AdrienGivry You can, it seems, instantiate a `child` before defining `parent`, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kk6xHNV8Fo4Fdu87

Comment: @AdrienGivry I think you mean that `parent` must be fully defined before instantiating one?

Comment: @RichardCritten At the moment I don't really care about the difference between c++11 and c++17. Therefore, I would like the answer for c++11 please.

Comment: @PaulSanders You shared an empty link ;)

Comment: @jan.sende Works for me, though it's not relevant to your q anyway.

Comment: The real question is simply how c++11 defines the requirement for `std::vector` to require a complete type. It may simply be that no diagnostics are required and standard library implementers are allowed to write an implementation that works for incomplete types. Though it won't be portable to use it that way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382714/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, nope because language lawyer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That has been my personal explanation so far. However, is there any guarantee in the standard for this behaviour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Standard says (draft N3690; this is post C++11, pre C++14):

> [res.on.functions]
>
> 1 In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions,
>   operations on types used to instantiate standard library template
>   components), the C++standard library depends on components supplied by
>   a C++program. If these components do not meet their requirements,
>   **the Standard places no requirements on the implementation**.
>
> 2 In particular, the **effects are undefined** in the following cases:
>
> — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when
>   instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for
>   that component.

Given that standard places no requirements, and effects are undefined (as far as I can tell, this is same as undefined behaviour), there is no expectation for the instantiation to "not work" any more than there is expectation for it to (appear to) "work".

---

Since C++17, the requirement was relaxed and `std::vector` does **not** require the value type to be complete, if used with appropriate allocator (the default allocator is appropriate). (This freedom does not extend to using all member functions; they have additional requirements).

Standard quote (current draft):

> [vector.overview]
>
> An incomplete type T may be used when instantiating vector if the allocator meets the allocator completeness requirements.
>   T shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of vector is referenced.
>
> [allocator.requirements.completeness]
>
> If X is an allocator class for type T, X additionally meets the allocator completeness requirements if, whether or not T is a complete type:
>
> - X is a complete type, and
> - all the member types of allocator_­traits other than value_­type are complete types.
>
> [default.allocator]
>
> All specializations of the default allocator meet the allocator completeness requirements ([allocator.requirements.completeness]).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The second paragraph remains relevant.

Comment: I think it would be a good answer if C++11 explanation is supported with a quote from standard.

Comment: @SergeyA I Added quote from a draft

Comment: @eerorika dully upvoted. For completeness, I would humbly suggest adding C++17 quote as well

Comment: So you are saying, that this is implementation defined?

Comment: @jan.sende No; implementation defined would mean that implementation needs to document (it's unspecified how such definition should be documented though) the behaviour. There is no requirement whatsoever. The program could compile, not compile, behave correctly, behave wrongly, on same or different compiler etc.

Comment: @SergeyA Added C++17 quote.

Comment: @eerorika So the behaviour is not defined? (Not in the sense of **undefined behaviour** though...)

Comment: @jan.sende I have no idea whether undefined behaviour is same or different that undefined "effects". From perspective of C++ programmer, I would assume that they mean exactly the same. If I was implementing a standard library, I would assume that I cannot make crazy optimisations based on that.

Comment: @eerorika Understood. Would you mind spelling out that this behaviour is not defined and therefore cannot be relied on. Then, I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @jan.sende I added now "(as far as I can tell, this is same as undefined behaviour)".

Comment: @jan.sende Undefined here implies that there is no guarantee that the code compiles; this is *unlike* the case of doing an illegal operation like a division by zero at runtime, where the code must compile and run for all execution that don't involve that illegal operation.

Comment: Reading it now .. specifically for C++11, does that means C++11 allows incomplete type for the vector<parents> in the above code yet the effect could be undefined? It might or it might not compile? Though i am not sure why C++11 allows incomplete type here.

Comment: @yapkm01 I wouldn't say "allow". "Behaviour is undefined" is generally seen to imply "don't do that". `It might or it might not compile? ` Correct.