# What are the rules for standard library containers and incomplete types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, incomplete-type

Given an incomplete type:

```
struct S;
```

Then the following declarations are:

```
S *p;            // ok, pointer to incomplete types is allowed

std::deque<S> l;  // error, instantiating std::deque with incomplete type is UB
```

But what about the following declarations?

```
std::deque<S> *p;   // seems to be UB like the previous case, 
                   // but is it ok if p is not used till S is defined?

std::deque<S*> p;   // not really sure about this one
```

Edit: the question used `std::list` instead of `std::deque`, but that defeats the purpose of the question, since `std::list` is explicitly [allowed](https://eel.is/c++draft/list.overview#3) to use incomplete types. `std::deque` doesn't appear to have such [permission](https://eel.is/c++draft/deque.overview).

Comment: I'd say `std::list<S*> p;` is fine. Shouldn't be a problem for compiler to generate a pointer to a struct without having its layout/size. ?

Comment: Kinda dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975491/why-does-stdvector-work-with-incomplete-types-in-class-definitions?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer No, I specifically chose `list` because I thought it didn't have permission to use incomplete types. But eeorika's answer suggests it is. I'll have to edit the question then.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Edited the question to use a container that doesn't allow incomplete types (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> std::deque<S> *p;   // seems to be UB like the previous case, 
>                    // but is it ok if p is not used till S is defined?
> ```

That's actually the interesting bit here. Yes, **instantiating** that container with an incomplete type is not allowed, there is no provision for it. But the question becomes whether or not it's really instantiated. It doesn't have to be, according to the core language.

> **[temp.inst]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#1) Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
> instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template
> specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
> referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type
> or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of
> the program.

A pointer to a type doesn't require the type to be complete. So this declaration alone is not normally enough to cause an instantiation of a class template, and so it may be premature to determine the requirement of the container is violated here.

Unless of course we take *"the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program"* to include contract violations in the standard library. An implementation *could* instantiate here, I suppose. I'm not aware of any implementation that does however, so this may not be the desires interpretation.

So to err on to side of caution, I'd deem this UB too.

---

> ```
> std::deque<S*> p;  // not really sure about this one
> ```

This is fine. Whether or not `S` is complete, `S*` is still a complete object type. I say this because it's not included at

> **[basic.types]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#5) A class that has been declared but not defined, an enumeration
> type in certain contexts ([dcl.enum]), or an array of unknown bound or
> of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type.
> Incompletely-defined object types and cv void are incomplete types
> ([basic.fundamental]). Objects shall not be defined to have an
> incomplete type.

The constraints about the completeness of `S` only appear when attempting to use such a pointer in an expressions that does a dereference or pointer arithmetic. But the pointer type itself is still complete. So it's a valid template argument for a container type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "premature to determine...". Is it definitely ok, or is an implementation allowed to reject this?

Comment: @cigien - Well, I read *"when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program"* as pretty broad. One can argue the completeness of *this type* affects the semantics of the program.

Comment: I would certainly think that *correctness* of a program is tied to *sematics* of the program. IMO the wording implies this is ok, but I'm mostly guessing here.

Comment: @cigien - Well, I summarized my musings in the last edit.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. I always prefer answers that take a stand, whether it's right or wrong :)