# What C++20 change to reverse_iterator is breaking this code?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, reverse-iterator

The following code compiles in C++11, C++14, and C++17, but does not compile in C++20. What change to the standard broke this code?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct bar
{
    typename T::reverse_iterator x;
};

struct foo
{
    bar<std::vector<std::pair<foo, foo>*>> x;
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
}
```

The error is quite long, but can be summarized as:

> template argument must be a complete class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was always undefined. [[res.on.functions]/2.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.functions-2.5) says:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - [...]
> - If an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

`std::pair` does not (and cannot) support incomplete types. You were just relying on order of instantiation to kind of get around that. Something changed in the library that slightly changed the evaluation order, leading to the error. But undefined behavior is undefined - it happened to work before and it happens to not work now.

---

As to why it's specifically C++20 that is causing this to fail. In C++20, iterators changed to have this new `iterator_concept` idea. In order to instantiate that, `reverse_iterator` needs to determine what the concept should be. That looks like [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4143efc1eed44050201b20c78d0206bc266e30c4/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h#L156-L164):

```
#if __cplusplus > 201703L && __cpp_lib_concepts
      using iterator_concept
    = conditional_t<random_access_iterator<_Iterator>,
            random_access_iterator_tag,
            bidirectional_iterator_tag>;
      using iterator_category
    = __detail::__clamp_iter_cat<typename __traits_type::iterator_category,
                     random_access_iterator_tag>;
#endif
```

Now, in the process of checking `random_access_iterator`, the root of iterator concept hierarchy is wonderfully named `input_or_output_iterator`, specified in [[iterator.concept.iterator]](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.iterator):

```
template<class I>
  concept input_or_output_iterator =
    requires(I i) {
      { *i } -> can-reference;
    } &&
    weakly_incrementable<I>;
```

So, we have to do `*i` on our iterator type. That's `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<foo, foo>**, std::vector<std::pair<foo, foo>*> >` , in this case. Now, `*i` triggers ADL - because of course it does. And ADL requires instantiation of all the associated types - because those associated types might have injected friends that could be candidates!

This, in turn, requires instantiating `pair<foo, foo>` - because, we have to check. And then that ultimately fails in this specific case because instantiating a type requires instantiating all of the type's special member functions, and the way that libstdc++ implements conditional assignment for `std::pair` is using [Eric Fisellier's trick](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4143efc1eed44050201b20c78d0206bc266e30c4/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_pair.h#L389-L398):

```
      _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR pair&
      operator=(typename conditional<
        __and_<is_copy_assignable<_T1>,
               is_copy_assignable<_T2>>::value,
        const pair&, const __nonesuch&>::type __p)
      {
    first = __p.first;
    second = __p.second;
    return *this;
      }
```

And `is_copy_assignable` requires complete types and we don't have one.

But really even if `pair` used concepts to check in this case, that would still involve instantiating the same type traits, so we'd ultimately end up in the same position.

Moral of the story is, undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Note the argument isn't a pair, it's a pointer to a pair. Ignoring pointer arithmetic, pointers to incomplete types are complete types, no?

Comment: @Pubby: But by typing the text `std::pair<T, T>`, you *require* the compiler to instantiate that template. And that instantiation requires `T` to be a complete type. It doesn't matter (for the most part) *where* you type that text.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think that's true. Consider literally any templated node class http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/655220ab33da9f2a

Comment: @Pubby: The template `node` does not use `T` in any way that requires it to be complete. `pair` does. When I said "that instantiation", I meant "`std::pair`'s instantiation", not instantiation in general.

Comment: @NicolBolas Consider a second example then. The compiler isn't instantiating the template when used in a pointer type: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/613ae814412efb4c

Comment: @Pubby I asked exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061188/what-are-the-rules-for-standard-library-containers-and-incomplete-types) recently. Conclusion there at least is that it's UB.