# Confusion (or Clang bug?) about incomplete types in std::vector

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, llvm, c++20

The C++20 standard [states in [vector.overview]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector#overview-4):

> An incomplete type T may be used when instantiating vector if the allocator meets the allocator
> completeness requirements.  T shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of
> vector is referenced.

The default allocator `std::allocate` does satisfy the `allocator completeness requirements`. The
main question is what "referenced" means in this context. The code I am confused about are variants of this:

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass;

class MyContainer
{ 
        std::vector<MyClass>  member;
};

class MyClass {};

int main()
{}
```

The above code compiles fine [in all sorts of compilers](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XG2NXUNWc0KQ93BvcX9sQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CYbbgBuFUTEh9gmGgCC1zc7TAoKewCyAJ5uBs%2BHVrf3j2eb0%2BsiYUwu/1iFgOtz2cL243QIBApwcJEObg%2BXyeCkucLYMwuGz%2Bd1iABFfvcAd8XliaQcoSZyZT/rdggQ9iwwQwIHMqYzyRwFrROABWXh%2BDhaUioThuazWBFLFaYA5mDY8UgETRChYITBMLAxXmkADWIA2GwAdJbbXb7QA2fScSS8FgSDQaUiS6Wyji8BQgL3aqVC0hwWAwRAoVAsBJ0aLkShoOMJmKPIxcUWe0hYY54VYANTwmAA7gB5BKMTiami0AjRQMQCI60gRYK1d413jt5jEd7liLaM7d0gptiCcsMWhd0O5zBcoziOf4YhnPCnQNzzCqCpeBuj9mtVu0PARYidjxYVsEYh4d3cMNUAzABTFsuV6uPmSCERidhSD%2B8hKGora6M0BhGCgCqWPoZ6BpACyoAk7RbgAtGhiKHGSpiWNYZjSuUlTOBArgjE0pCBFMRQlNkySpAI5F0bkaQ9DR/RjK064CJ0wyeI0ehEe0vGTIUfQxGMExMZJXRseJEgLAoyqrApzocOK3qtn6eyqAAHA6aEOpIewZsAexZlaGiWXsEC4IQJBqhqcy8CGWhzHqBpGpQCzmtmamuqQ7oEVasQaPpDpSFwsQbGYZi6Zamlzn6AZBlqOoLBG0ZLAQCT7kmEApvG9DEKErBrHpBlGSZkFmRZVnSpg%2BDnHgSLNPwv6iOIgHtcBKjqHO4GkKWF4JN2wpihKWmcOW%2B65RyqBUDp%2BmGcZpnmaKlnWRAHipsVjlcM5aWhu5pD6oa/QmiKHABe6sQAJxWmYd1cJaumirpZgOrEsRcE6Pq8Mltipa5upmha1r2pDtpOldGyTUlnAuel4ZRplEBIIVab5ZjxUgMAXCxfO%2BZFiWFZVpKtZ0A2xBNi2c69p2o4M/2g7Dg4o7jowBBTjOrZYIuwDLtKq7rpurY7nuB7fkeV3Sqe56XhgazSre95jXwL5vqTn4U7wPV/l10g9YofVgSAZj6IYxgwTY8sISayGoZwGFYRsOE2wRAZccRfikQw7j8aMlH%2B3JhLMQx6SBxROQR6HtGcW0VRSVHgne8JExxxxgxdNJ2d1JnEmKcpAHjep8O%2BpwS2VcZwDIMg5lmI9Nl2ec%2B2HSDJ3mpaNpQ5D/luhaVmxJIcW6bEZiSHd0UOqKM%2BJRX/pA8GyNoxjsZFYmFAFevaYoDVUg5nmBaYO%2BZNfpT9aNpQdPSszs6anfrMjt%2BnOTtOs7CwuVtC7wIuVGL25dzIH3GsTUMsTxngvP2K8ysXJ3gfDwBYz4mCvlPjrUc%2BtOoASNrIE2oEBoWktlBXCVhYJ23gEhFCaR0KYQIOgbCJD8KETTmkFw/tc5UTEmHZoMd2i514axai8kE7cQ6MnTIFEhJJ1kkI7hed6gpxkvnWR8ci7LBUgdNSGl/oykrhVFa1UrbmUkJtDQzcmoOU2AdJGx0PLnWNKXG64MbQOg2O9B0Zh7rqjnjowGgZl7HRRvAdGMZdqb2TDvXGpksyH0wMTE%2B2tyYYKplfZsrY75Mw7CzIcz9NSv25u/PmX8lywNzHgNc/9MBbgakAkBh5BDHjnPLKBIJrxzlVggp8ms0FJO/Jg/8EgcGCDwf1aUuhpA1WgnhMh8EKEyioQIGhrt3bTIsFFL2icSJkUUcHdABdw58J2QI/IKis5SJ4uIgSIifYiX2UohREjBIZ1OYXRY6iS5aPLgDPRy0qprTqltFulj1TWKOm5OxXlLougHm4q0uk7puM%2BpIH6GhPp3UkKKee3zF7%2BLBaDLuENe72jUnDLFujF4d1LmYL55KbHgtIKcGmrDJBAA%3D%3D%3D). It [still compiles](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBLSAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CoeFRLLHxXLaY9vkMQgRMxASZPn6BdpgO6bX1BIWRMXEJtnUNTdnlCsM9YX0lA1wAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2BbgBu7UTEh9gmGgCC1zc7TAoKewCyAJ5uBs%2BHVrf3j2eb0%2BsiY0wu/wA7BYDrc9vDgR5BGDwsQIPN4YcACJ7LBUJheWgEX73BF7CboEAgU4OEiHNwfL5PBSXeFsWYXfx/O6QrEk/63QEvRnfF4maHivlc%2B73MIEPYsFHomUS3kcRa0TgAVl4fg4WlIqE4bms1nJy1WmAOZn8PFIBE06sWCEwTCw8XRpAA1gF/AA6fyBoPB4MANn0nEkvBYEg0GlIeoNRo4vAUIHjDv16tIcFgMEQKFQLESdDi5EoaGLpfijyMXC1cdIWGOeDWADU8JgAO4AeUSjE4dpoRLiaYg0UdpGiYXq70HvGnzGI7x70W0Z3npErbEEPYYtDnWabmEVRnER/wxDOeFOaaPmFU7S8BHWdrllUntDw0WIs48WEnAhiDwGNuGzKgDGABQO27PsBzAmRBBEMR2CkRD5CUNRJ10coDCMFBTUsfRvzTSBFlQRJqjvABaaiKWxUxLGsMwDTaDpnAgVxRj8coQmmYpShyFI0gEbihLydJegEuYKiqTpJjE8ZKmvAQugaKT%2BjKIZukU7T1P4zSJEWBQLTWIyIw4HUE0nZM9lUAAOUNqNDSQ9lrYA9nrP0NG8vYIFwQgSGtW15l4TMtHmZ1XXdShFh9BsLKjUgYxYv1IQ0RzQykLhIX8MwzHswNrKPZNU3Te1HUWXMC2WAhEmfcsIErEt6GICJWHWBynJcty8I8ryfINTB8HOPBKXKfgkNEcQ0MmjCVHUI8cNILtf0SecNW1XUbM4Htn3q%2BVUCoOzHOc1z3M8rVvN8iAPCrVrgoWMLKqit0Bk9TUOCSmNIQATj9Mxfq4QN7K1eyzFDSFIS4cNE14UrbHK8KnW9X0AxDDHA3DT7/G2krOGerMqvzaqICQZrq0ainWpAYAuHy48W3bTte37PUhzoF9iDHCcj0XWdN355dV3XBxN23RgCD3A9JywU9gHPA1L2vW9JwfJ8X03d9PoNL8fz/DB1gNICQI2vhIOglm4PZ3g5uQmbpDmxQFuwkAzH0QxjEImw9dIz0KKozhaPo/wsUYqxLBY1NlPYvxOIYdxPGaPQ%2BKKQzylyESMiTsZSEz6oNI5PQ2OqNTGhznjZJUmpJkLwTxgUivi9rgyi4WJYVjM9vPqsuHDU4E7utc4BkGQTyzABvyAvOR7Qoqom4rRzHMcS6MAh8yFJAK%2BzITMSRfty0MtSP4qkwJxGM0qnMSfJosWrLCgmrv6sUD6qRG2bVtMBg1n4I5kduaUF5gaIWh47SgJFhuBCEtdz7kPErE8ntFa8GVh0VW95HzIGfK%2BXg2tPzfl/Muf8RswrAVAjwRYEEmBQR/tbTcdtpqoUdrIZ2WEloBA9vhcO1hiLRD9uRSi6QaJ0QIOgBi3so5V1ji4BOulU4zHrnnYS1RdL50kq3RRJd5I6SbkpOSqkW5pzbnpcuWRK4TG6HXOYxlTKoU2pZPGZ8OCDzOr1T2nlJDXQ0FPEaQVNhPXnhFV6MUPqRjXoGAMoZ/Bg1DGYP6NoT59wRmmS%2BRNr7wDJoWe6D8KzPxpu5esH9MBM2/lbNm9DOajiAZOUBgsZzCzXFAu0MCpZwNlogs8JCmx4CvGgzAd4hqYOwVrQQH4jx60ISCACR4TbkPAhbWh5SEIMJQoMJ2mFFoGl0NIPqBEmJEV9vAARgcODB1EeI/ZFgcrR30XHLiuiggJysVpNRokHmvIYM84uMdS6NzMd825ZcvkNx0f8kF%2BkjH1xsZ3OxFle47WcV1VxF0Bo3Wnn4m0ATkaRVIC6N6Hp7HfQCFdeyv1okQ0kNDDQENfqSC1KfeG58UmBJRj6CJy8MYWVxgy/uKYWU4s%2BmYRxjK%2BXYsWKcbm6QQCSCAA%3D%3D%3D) if I explicitly default the default constructor:

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass;

class MyContainer
{ 
        MyContainer()  = default;
        std::vector<MyClass>  member;
};

class MyClass {};

int main()
{}
```

However, when I instead define the default constructor to be "empty", something weird happens. This is the code ([here at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM1ykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BfgG2mPZFDPWNBCWRMXGJtg1NLbntCmP9YYPlwwkAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmO24AbjVExKfYJhoAgvcPB0wKCkcAsgCebgbvpysj2er3eX1%2BsiYcxuwISFhOjyOSPBHkEUPCxAgSxOcJMCQAIoDnsijtN0CAQJcHCRTm4fn83gpbki2AsbjsgU8CUTgY9QR96f8PnirNyOc9nmECEcWOisRLcQSOCtaJwAKy8PwcLSkVCcNzWayktYbTAnMw7HikAiaZUrBCYJhYeJY0gAaxAOx2ADovX7/QGAGz6TiSXgsCQaDSkLU6vUcXgKEDRm3a5WkOCwGCIFCoFjJOhxciUND5wvxV5GLhqqOkLDnPCbABqeEwAHcAPLJRicK00WgEOJJiDRW2kaJhRrfXu8CfMYjfDvRbRXGekUtsQQdhi0adpuuYWVGcT7/DEK54S5J/eYVQ1LyDtdSzpj2h4aLEKceLBjgjEPARtw6ZUAYwAKC27Zdj2QEyIIIhiOwUiwfIShqGOuiBAYRgoIalj6O%2BSaQCsqDJN014ALTkWSpz4qYljWGYOrVLUzgQK4Ex%2BIEIRzGUFR6AUGQCBx/FpIJDADLxwyBMx3S9OMnitHoMl1DMElDPE0kzMJml9GpbISCsCgmpsBkhhwGoxmO8ZHKoAAcgbkYGkhHJWwBHNW3oaJ5RwQLghAkOalpLLwqZaEs9qOs6lArB6NZmWGpARox3oJBo9mBlIXAJDsZhmLZXqWfu8aJsm1q2ismY5msBDJA%2BxYQKWBb0MQESsFsdkOU5LlYW5HleTqmD4NceDkoE/BwaI4hIeNKEqOo%2B4YaQbafskM4quqmpWZwHYPrV0qoFQNn2Y5zmue5aqed5EAeGWzWBVwwVlWm4WkA6TrDK6qocAlEYJAAnN6Zh/VwXq2WqtlmIGCQJFwwaxrwxW2KVoV2u6no%2BgGmN%2BsGX07JtRWcCF5UZtmlUQEgjXlvVlPNSAwBcLlB4Ns2radt2Wp9nQg7EMOo77nOU5rgLC5LiuDhrhujAENuu5jlgR7ACeOpnheV5jre96PjBz5fTqb4fl%2BGBbDqf4AWtfCgeBrNQRzvAzfBU3SDNihzeh/j6IYxi4TY%2BuEa6JFkZwlHUTstHe4xiadBerHsQpuRcQw6B6Xx%2BSid02kpGnmTJ1JHRdCpfQZ8pAhybMpTqUpWlx5xoy6TxFcPas6wmY3X0WfDuqcEdnXOcAyDIO5ZiAz5fnXPdj0oy9Hper6WOY/F4ael5CSSHltkJGYkh/dlgZqrvhVxoTSMpsTZMU3mTVFhQDUX%2BWKA9VItb1o2mAQWz0GcwOQ6UHzOrC3uVp/6i1XDBSWW4dx7mVoeT2SteAq1qGrG8d5kAPi2FaHWr53yfgXN%2BY2IV/yAR4CsECTAwJvxtmue2k1EJO1kC7NCC1PQe2wnRKweFfbwGIqRTIFEqIEHQDRVhDEmJRxYn4NiicM7cXLvpVOhRMgZwEt0HOGk87Rx6FXHINdi4aLrjIlOtd5JaMrno%2BYKdDLGUQutcy%2BND4cG7idbqnt3KSEuhoEeQ0Aq7AekTZ6EV3oumsT9dGvpAw7HBoGMw/0LT7w7ojJMJ9nok3gOTXMt0r4llvrTVy1Yn6YGZq/a27NKFc2/iOMc/8haThFsuEBVowHSwgXLaBx48F1jwOeBBmBrwDWQagp8ggXz7n1tgiEP59ym0IcBS25DikwSoQhCQtDBD0PmjqXQ0geo4XouwginDdTcIELwkOYcdkWCypHfOMdJHVz0NIsxuclEKNuXIsSKilKiNkpoxS0lPkFyaO8nSRifmGLLg8jSFjm5WLMu3La9iOqOLOn1K6o8vEWh8U9MK/ioqfVDIvcJ3pbJ/XCZDSQMMNCQz%2BpINUB8EZHwSZi1G08MZzwDGZPGtLO4JkZS9L6ZhbF0u5ZPFYlweaZBAJIIAA)):

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass;

class MyContainer
{ 
        MyContainer() {};
        std::vector<MyClass>  member;
};

class MyClass {};

int main()
{}
```

With this code:

- GCC 12, Clang 14 and Clang 15 in C++17-mode still compile this
- Clang 15 in C++20-mode fails with this error:

```
    In file included from <source>:1:
    In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/vector:64:
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:367:35: error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'MyClass'
                                                _M_impl._M_end_of_storage - _M_impl._M_start);
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:526:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Vector_base<MyClass, std::allocator<MyClass>>::~_Vector_base' requested here
                vector() = default;
                ^
    <source>:7:5: note: in defaulted default constructor for 'std::vector<MyClass>' first required here
            MyContainer() {};
            ^
    <source>:3:7: note: forward declaration of 'MyClass'
    class MyClass;
```

My first instinct, only looking at the Clang 15 error, was "clang is correct". The default
constructor does (implicitly) invoke the default constructor of `std::vector<MyClass>`, and the
standard says that you cannot reference members as long as `MyClass` is incomplete.

However, I'm pretty much sure that this cannot be the answer since:

- All the other compilers (see above) do not even warn
- The Thrift C++ compiler actually produces code that does exactly this.

So, my question is: Is this a Clang 15 bug? And if so, is (implicitly) invoking the default
constructor of `std::vector<MyClass>` not considered a "reference" in terms of [vector.overview]/4?

I did [search the LLVM bug tracker](https://bugs.llvm.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=vector%20incomplete) for the terms "vector" and "incomplete", but that did not turn
something up, so if this is a known bug, it's not known in the context of `std::vector`, I guess.

---

### Edit 1: I don't think this is a duplicate

This was closed as a duplicate of two questions, which in my opinion, is incorrect. The differences are subtle but relevant. The two questions are:

##### [std::map::reverse_iterator doesn't work with C++20 when used with incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343631/stdmapreverse-iterator-doesnt-work-with-c20-when-used-with-incomplete-typ)

- [The std::map specification](https://eel.is/c++draft/map) never says (contrary to the std::vector specification, see [vector.overview]/4) that it can be instantiated with an incomplete type. Thus, the problem in my question (with std::vector) is not the same as the problem with std::map
- In the question, an object of the offending std::map is instantiated before the incomplete type was made complete - this can obviously never work. In my question, no object is instantiated at all.

##### [What C++20 change to reverse_iterator is breaking this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195302/what-c20-change-to-reverse-iterator-is-breaking-this-code)

- Here, a member of `std::vector<incompleteType>` is explicitly referenced (namely `::reverse_iterator`). This is obviously not covered by [vector.overview]/4. However, I'm not doing that in my question.
- Again, an object of the vector-with-incomplete-type is instantiated before the type was made complete, which cannot work and which I'm also not trying to do.

Comment: fwiw, if your code has UB then compilers are not mandated to warn or diagnose it. They might if they can and if you are lucky.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I would suspect somebody to notice if the Thrift compiler generated UB-ridden code for (rather simple) examples. So I'd like to figure out whether Clang 15 (in C++20 mode) is truly correct here (and all other compilers - including Clang 15 in C++17 mode - are wrong) before I file that as a Thrift bug.

Comment: sure, my point was just that others not reporting it is very weak evidence for clang being wrong.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/b4G7xab56

Comment: It s weird, since default constructor with `= defult;` or `{}` are equivalent, so compiler should behave in the same meaner. Anyway I would fix code using version 2 (see link above).

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for the nice overview on Godbolt, good idea. Yes, that would make everything compile again. Unfortunately I see this problem in code generated by the Thrift C++ generator, which I can not (or do not want to) modify manually.

Comment: @MarekR • A `= default;` *defaulted default constructor* is not actually equivalent to a `{}` user-provided inline constructor.  For example, the defaulted one allows the type to still be trivial, the user-provided one does not.  There are some other small [differences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), which usually don't matter... until they matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that "referenced" is not clear here. What I think this sentence probably means is that `T` shall be complete before you do anything that would require the definition of any member of the resulting specialization to exist.

In the second example

```
class MyClass;

class MyContainer
{ 
        MyContainer()  = default;
        std::vector<MyClass>  member;
};

class MyClass {};
```

the definition of `std::vector<MyClass>`'s default constructor is not needed until the compiler actually implicitly defines the default constructor of the enclosing class, `MyContainer`. And that doesn't happen until the first time `MyContainer`'s default constructor is either odr-used or needed for constant evaluation, per the last sentence of [[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#5.sentence-6):

> A non-user-provided defaulted function (i.e. implicitly declared or explicitly defaulted in the class) that is not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) or needed for constant evaluation ([expr.const]).

Your first example, where you didn't declare any default constructor, and your second example, where you declared it as defaulted inside the class definition, are treated similarly: in both cases the constructor is non-user-provided, so it does not get eagerly defined. In both examples, `MyContainer` has a non-user-provided copy constructor, move constructor, copy-assignment operator, move-assignment operator, and destructor, which likewise are not defined until their definitions are needed, so the program avoids "referencing" any members of `std::vector<MyClass>`.

In the third example, because the constructor is user-provided, it is defined even if it is never used, and its definition implicitly calls the default constructor of `std::vector<MyClass>`, *i.e.*, the latter is "referenced".

When you break the rules, as you did in the third example, the program has undefined behaviour. I understand that it seems awfully unfriendly that most compilers you tried don't even warn you, but there is a reason why diagnostics are not required when you misuse incomplete types: it's difficult for templates to check for completeness in a way that does not cause bigger problems (though I believe there is ongoing work on this issue in Clang).