# Early instantiation of non-template method of template class

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following class:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct my_struct {
    my_struct() {}
    explicit my_struct(T) {}
    explicit my_struct(std::vector<T>) {}
};

int main() {    
    my_struct<const int> s1(1);
}
```

The use case is that the third constructor should only be called in some instanciations of `my_struct`, and not in some other cases (e.g. with const types). It is what is done here in the `main`: it is **not** called.

I get a compiler error (GCC, Clang, Intel). GCC error message : `/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:401:66: error: static assertion failed: std::vector must have a non-const, non-volatile value_type`

In fact, it has nothing to do with `std::vector` (but the compilers are pretty bad at giving us any clue). It can be reproduced with a very similar code:

```
class my_class {
    static_assert(0, "should not be used");
};

template<class T>
struct my_struct {
    my_struct() {}
    explicit my_struct(T) {}
    explicit my_struct(my_class) {}
};

int main() {
    my_struct<int> s(1); // error
}
```

The problem, as I interpret it, is that once `my_struct` is instanciated, it results in a concrete type, and the compiler may instanciate all its methods. In this case, it instanciates `my_struct(my_class)`, so it instanciates `my_class`, so we get the static error.

**note:** we might get "lucky" however: in the `vector` case, calling only `my_struct()` does not trigger the error (something to do with overload resolution I guess)

**note:** the way I fix the error is by templating the constructor instead of using `vector`:

```
template<class vector_type>
my_struct(vector_type) {}
```

I find it ugly but have no other idea.

0. Is my interpretation of what is going on correct?
1. Is this behavior required / left undefined by the language? Or is it a compiler bug?
2. If yes, I would call it a language defect in C++17 at least. Would you agree?
3. If yes, is there a language defect report? Is it corrected in C++20?
4. If no: how would you solve the problem? Is it a design problem?
5. Could we expect the compilers to have, in a not too distant future, a more detailed stack trace of what is going on? At least mentionning why it needs to instanciate a type that is never called by the concrete class at hand.

Comment: 1) `static_assert(0, "should not be used");` is [invalid per se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere), and this is unrelated to `std::vector<const int>`. 2) I suggest that you also the add language standard tag. E.g., C++17 and C++20 solutions would be different.

Comment: I once concluded that an implementation is within its right to eagerly [instantiate a standard library template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061188/what-are-the-rules-for-standard-library-containers-and-incomplete-types) since its constraints impact program validity. You have a similar case, it would seem.

Comment: Although, GCC has no qualms about the vector when it's passed by reference. So there's that.

Comment: @Evg Added both C++17 and C++20 because I would like the answer for both obviously

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes but I want to pass as a sink argument in order to move, so a reference is not an option

Comment: Hmmm. [The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, ... of the class member functions ...](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2) and incomplete types are allowed in function declarations. However, both GCC and Clang complain about incomplete types in parameters of a class template's member functions. (Even though Clang accepts non-member function declarations with incomplete types in parameters).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But since vector is taken by value, doesn't it have to be a complete type even if we were to look only at the declaration ?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer so, regardless of my previous comment, you would rather lean towards GCC and Clang being too eager when instanciating methods?

Comment: _But since vector is taken by value, doesn't it have to be a complete type even if we were to look only at the declaration ?_ No, a type doesn't need to be complete in a function declaration parameters, only in definition ones. And class template need not be instantiated if the complete type is not required. To my understanding, `vector<const int>` need not be instantiated.

Comment: _However, both GCC and Clang complain about incomplete types in parameters of a class template's member functions_ BTW, it seems they are allowed, but the corresponding issue is not officially resolved yet.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer *the corresponding issue is not officially resolved yet* Do you have a GCC/Clang issue where they talk about it? You can post it as an answer I think

Comment: It is a CWG issue. And it is not 100% related, because I meant non-dependent incomplete type.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer CWG?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The parameter type must be instantiated to perform overload resolution since it might be constructible from the argument type.  (With a reference, the implementation is allowed to skip instantiation ([temp.inst]/9).)

Comment: @DavisHerring indeed.

Answer (score 4):

As of C++20, you can make use of constraint expressions as introduced by a trailing requires clause to constrain the instantiation of the third constructor for a given instantiation of the `my_struct` class template to some predicate on the type template parameter `T` of the class template:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct my_struct {
    my_struct() {}
    explicit my_struct(T) {}
    explicit my_struct(std::vector<T>) requires (!std::is_const_v<T>) {}
};

int main() {
    my_struct<const int> s(1);
    my_struct<int> t({1, 2});
}
```

Other than using a less complex syntax as compared to the pre-C++20 `std::enable_if_t` SFINAE approach, it also doesn't force you to make the constructor a template function solely such that the constructor itself is parameterized over a type template parameter that participates in the deduction process when the constructor is a candidate function in overload resolution.

Particularly, [[temp.constr.constr]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#2) states [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[temp.constr.constr]/2**
>
> In order for **a constrained template to be instantiated**
> ([temp.spec]), **its associated constraints shall be satisfied** as
> described in the following subclauses. [*Note*: Forming the name of a
> specialization of a class template, a variable template, or an alias
> template ([temp.names]) requires the satisfaction of its constraints.
> **Overload resolution requires the satisfaction of constraints on functions** and function templates. — *end note*]

where the particular associated constraint in this case is covered by [[temp.constr.decl]/3.3.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#3.3.4):

> **[temp.constr.decl]/3**
>
> A declaration's *associated constraints* are defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - *(3.3)* Otherwise, the associated constraints are the normal form of a logical AND expression whose operands are in the following order:
>
>   - [...]
>   - *(3.3.4)* the *constraint-expression* introduced by a trailing *requires-clause* ([dcl.decl]) of a function declaration ([dcl.fct]).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::enable_if` to disable the vector constructor when `T` is `const`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct my_struct {
    my_struct() {}
    explicit my_struct(T) {}
    template <typename U = T>
    explicit my_struct(std::vector<U>, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<U>, int> = 0) {}
};

int main() {
    my_struct<const int> s(1);
    my_struct<int> t({1, 2});
}
```

Comment: You might want to say that the extra template parameter is required here.