# Using default copy constructor corrupts a tree in C++

Tags: c++

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
    vector<TreeNode> children;
    string name;
};

int main() {
    TreeNode leafNode;
    leafNode.name="c";
    TreeNode middleNode;
    middleNode.name="b";
    middleNode.children.push_back(leafNode);
    TreeNode rootNode;
    rootNode.name="a";
    rootNode.children.push_back(middleNode);
    rootNode=rootNode.children[0];
    cout <<rootNode.name <<endl;
}
```

Outputs `c`, in both CLANG and GCC. Of course, I'd expect it to output `b`. What's going on here?

Comment: Have you debugged the code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't managed to install a debugger on my Linux machine.

Comment: Well, a debugger should be part of your overall C++ development environment, else it is not a development environment.

Comment: Try it with `gdb` for gcc and `lldb` for clang. It's probably already installed.

Comment: OK, what should I do with a debugger here? How will it help me understand what's going on?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975491/why-does-stdvector-work-with-incomplete-types-in-class-definitions).

Comment: `rootNode=rootNode.children[0];` this assignment doesn't look sound. I suppose the assigned object is destroyed before it's read (rootNode.children is cleared prior to copy).

Comment: When you write `rootNode=rootNode.children[0]`, you are erasing middleNode (from rootNode's children) by the same object middleNode, it's unusual I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should **really** try to setup a debugger and debug your code first. That is how you learn a lot in programming.

However, if you are not used to debugging it will probably be hard for you to find the issue, since the code in question is compiler generated.

You are right that the copy constructor more or less *corrupts* your data. But that is not the compilers fault.
The default copy constructor takes its argument by reference and you are passing a reference of a member of `rootNode` to the copy constructor of `rootNode`. So in effect you are overwriting the object with a part of itself.

What more or less happens during the assignment or copy:

```
TreeNode(const TreeNode& other) {
  children = other.children;
  name = other.name;
}
```

So if you pass `rootNode.children[0]` to this operation, it will effectively be reduced to this:

```
rootNode.children = rootNode.children[0].children; // copies the children of 'b' to 'a'
rootNode.name     = rootNode.children[0].name;     // children[0] now refers to the first 
                                                   // of 'b's children, so name will be 'c' !!
```

A possible workaround is to create a true copy first using:

`rootNode = TreeNode{ rootNode.children[0] };`

The behavior might be different depending on the compiler. In VS2019 I get an empty output when trying your example.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use self assignment or self copy construction.
There is partial assignment `rootNode=rootNode.children[0];`
To avoid this problem should use pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory> // for std::shared_ptr

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode; // forward declaration

using TreeNodePtr = std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>;

struct TreeNode {
    vector<TreeNodePtr> children;
    string name;
};

int main() {
    auto leafNode = std::make_shared<TreeNode>();
    leafNode->name="c";
    auto middleNode = std::make_shared<TreeNode>();
    middleNode->name="b";
    middleNode->children.push_back(leafNode);
    auto rootNode = std::make_shared<TreeNode>();
    rootNode->name="a";
    rootNode->children.push_back(middleNode);
    rootNode=rootNode->children[0];
    cout <<rootNode->name <<endl;
}
```