# Why is an incomplete type allowed in std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

In the following code, although `Node` is an incomplete type at the time of the `vector` declaration, my C++ compiler (g++) does not report any warnings or errors.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    struct Node {
      std::vector<Node> children;
    };
    Node n;
    Node n2;
    n.children.push_back(n2);
}
```

How does the compiler handle this?

Comment: [Why does std::vector work with incomplete types in class definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975491/why-does-stdvector-work-with-incomplete-types-in-class-definitions).

Comment: Do you want to know the actual machinery the compiler uses to handle this, or just want to know why this allowed?

Comment: @Ruks exact duplicate!